# Rails 3 joins table and model naming conventions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am running Ruby 2.1.9 and Rails 3.2.17.

First off, in Rails I always made the assumption that models should almost always be singular. I have seen model names like product_categories_product. This is fine and in habtm situation where you want a model to work with the relationship I have seen instructions_products. Which in Rails sorta may make sense, but I would rather name the model instruction_product. That was associated with a joins table named instructions_products.

In fact I was so frustrated I started looking at how rails names things and this happened? So clearly its an ok name for the model and would correspond to the correct table name. But what is more approriate?

```
ActiveModel::Naming.singular(InstructionsProducts)
```

returns `instructions_products`

Edited: The heart of the question is why is InstructionsProducts a valid model name in rails and why does my example above resolve to the singular 'instructions_products'. This seems odd considering the rails convention is to keep model names singular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not completely clear to me.

By Rails conventions, model names are singular and written in camel case, for instance `InstructionProduct`. Each model matches a table in the database with the same words, down-cased, separated by '_' and in plural. `instruction_products` for the provided example.

Look at the following example using [has_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belong_to :name
end

user = User.find(1)
user.contacts # returns an array of all the associated objects
```

When doing `user.contacts`, contacts is not the table name. It's the collection method, a placeholder for the symbol passed in the has_many method (please follow the has_many link and read what documentation says about has_many). Another name could be used, though:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :personal_contacts, class_name: 'Contact' #, foreign_key: :contact_id
end

user = User.find(1)
user.personal_contacts
```

The class_name and foreign_key are required because rails conventions are not being followed. When using `has_many :personal_contacts` rails expects that `personal_contacts` will return an array of `PersonalContact`.

In Ruby you must start a class name with a capital word, so it is not possible to create a class named `instruction_product`. If you want to provide a name that does not follow the Rails convention, which I don't recommend, you will need to inform rails about the new table name:

```
Class AdminUser
  self.table_name = "users"
end
```

**Update 1:**

As you already know, the convention states that the model should be declared as singular (`class InstructionProduct` instead `class InstructionsProducts`. However its just a convention. When a class inherits from ActiveRecord::Base, and a sql query is generated, ActiveRecord lowercases the class name, separates the words by _, converts to a plural name and uses it as the table name (mainly rails uses `InstructionsProducts.model_name.plural` which returns `instructions_products`).

You are assuming that singular actually does a name translation to singular, even if it's written in plural, but it doesn't. It assumes that you are using the convention, and mainly returns the class name underscored.

Looking at the rails source code ([ActiveModel::Name](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/52ce6ece8c8f74064bb64e0a0b1ddd83092718e1/activemodel/lib/active_model/naming.rb#L154)), ActiveSupport::Inflector.underscore seems to be used (I just did a very superficial investigation, I have to admit). You can see how [underscore](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-underscore) works at documentation.

Comment: I understand that the class name must be capitalized and instruction_product is not a valid class name. Why is InstructionsProducts a valid model name in rails?

Comment: @AndrewStuntz I provided more clarifications, let me know.

Comment: I am not 100% satisfied by this answer but none the less it is an answer. Thank you. I will do some more research myself. I think my main issue was I was looking at the incorrect method on how rails handles the table name. I will update if I find anything more interesting.

Comment: @AndrewStuntz Let me know how it goes. I think the best way is to look at the rails source code. You can use RubyMine for code drill down.